# Insert Json object to database in php

Tags: php, json, postman

I am working on an android app which uses APIs made with php. Here, i am dynamically creating columns and their values.

I am verifying the API via postman and a strange thing happens every time, While looping through the Json Object what i am doing is first creating column and then inserting its values. 
The problem is only the 1st iteration saves the element and rest of them only creates the column but does not insert the values. I don't know if i am doing anything wrong, below is my php code.

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json_data = json_decode($data);



    foreach($json_data as $key => $val) {
       $column_name = $key ;
      $c_column_name = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]+/', '', $column_name);
       $column_value = $val ; 
       $table_name = "test2";
       $email = "ht@t.com";



    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table_name LIKE '$c_column_name'");
    $exists = (mysqli_num_rows($result))?TRUE:FALSE;
     if($exists) {
        $query1 = "INSERT INTO  $table_name($c_column_name)VALUES('$column_value') ";
        $data0=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
           if($data0)
          {
           echo json_encode(array("success"=>"true - insertion","message"=>"Column existed, Successfully data sent.")); 
          }
          else{
          echo json_encode(array("success"=>"false - insertion","message"=>"Column existed,  data not inserted.")); 

          }
    }

    else{

      $query2="ALTER TABLE $table_name ADD COLUMN `$c_column_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL";

      $data1=mysqli_query($conn,$query2);
      if($data1){

         $query3="INSERT INTO  $table_name($c_column_name)VALUES('$column_value')";
          $data2=mysqli_query($conn,$query3);
          if($data2)
          {
          echo json_encode(array("success"=>"true - insertion","message"=>"Successfully data sent.")); 
          }
          else{
          echo json_encode(array("success"=>"false - insertion","message"=>"Column created but data not inserted.")); 

          }
      }

      else
      {
            echo json_encode(array("success"=>"false - column creation","message"=>"Failed to create column.'$column_name', '$table_name', '$conn'"));
      }
    }
    }
?>
```

Here is the Json Object through postman.

```
{"Shape":"rewq","Trans.No.":"yuuiop","Color":"qwert"}
```

Please help me with this, any help or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like it would be more suitable in document-oriented DB to me.

Comment: okay i understand , cant we do this in sql ones ? we  can i think

Comment: `$json_data = json_decode($data, true);`

Comment: Sure. Though it depends what you're trying to achieve. Runtime manipulation of database schemas is not a path I would generally recommend. Another option depending on DB version would be to simply store the data _as_ json. Or simple key value table with an id table to tie them together is another option.

Comment: I tried converting it to array, but does not helped a lot , I think more changes needed in my logic below after i set (true)  @Anuga

Comment: @JonStirling can you tell me more about the second option ..

Comment: Can try. Let's say you're storing user data. So you have a table called `user`, you create a user, so you have a row with a user ID. Next you have a request from that user to store some arbitrary key-value data. So you have a table called e.g. `user_data` with the columns `id`, `user_id`, `key`, `value`. So you can loop over your JSON, and add a row for each pair e.g. a row for `user_id` of the current user, `Shape` for the `key` column, and `rewq` as the value, then the same for `Trans.No` etc.

Comment: Beware sql injection.

Comment: Where @LajosArpad

Comment: VALUES('$column_value') does not protect against SQL injection. What if $column_value is ');delete from test2 where ')'='

Comment: ohh , I am just trying this right now but thanks for that suggestion ...

Answer (score 0):

The second column name is `Trans.No.` which contains a dot, this is why it fails, probably you have an error as a result which prevents further columns from being created.

I think it would be much better to have a table with this structure:

attributes(id, key, value)

and whenever a key-value pair is received, you just insert/update it, depending on the logic you need to be executed. Your current model will create a separate row for each attribute, which is probably not what you want to achieve.

EDIT

Based on the information received in the comment section I reached the following conclusion:

You could create the missing columns first and then generate the insert statement with all the columns, having a single insert.

But it would be better to not create a separate column for each value, as the number of columns could quickly get out of hand. Instead you could have a table:

myentity(id, name)

for storing the entities represented by the JSON and

attributes(id, myentity_id, key, value)

for storing its attributes. This would be a neat schema with all the dinamicity you could want.

Comment: hey thanks for looking on to that , this problem of Trans. i had earlier and resolves it with        ** $c_column_name = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]+/', '', $column_name);**

Comment: @prashantkumarsingh please tell me what the $column_name and $c_column_name value is in each case.

Comment: Also, I just tried adding {"Color":"BLK"} it adds column and value then I tried {"Supplier":"Shed"} it fails to insert data only creates column

Comment: ex: column_name = Trans.No. after removing everything the characters  c_column_name  = TransNo

Comment: And what I want is if my object is  {"Shape":"rewq","Trans.No.":"yuuiop","Color":"qwert"}  then want a separate row for this object in which key as column and values as column values

Comment: @prashantkumarsingh check out my suggestion, it should achieve what you want, but with a much better schema. Also, do you get any errors?

Comment: your suggestion (id,key,value) will create every row for one entry say if my obj is {"Shape":"RND","Color":"BLK"} then this will be created as (id,key,value) ~ (1,Shape,RND) [1st row] and [2nd row] (2,Color,BLK) ............... is this what you mean ??

Comment: @prashantkumarsingh yes. Would you like them to be stored in a single record for a given JSON?

Comment: @prashantkumarsingh in this case your implementation is wrong, as it attempts to insert a separate row for each attribute. You could first add the missing columns to the table and then do a single insert.

Comment: You mean I first create all the columns for the keys and then insert values in the columns ???? first looping for the columns then for the values ???

Comment: @prashantkumarsingh if you have columns c1, c2, c3 and need c4 and c5 as well, then you will want to create columns c4 and c5 first and when your schema has already changed, do an insert into yourtable(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5) values(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5)

Comment: my table only has id (auto increamented) , rest of the columns are supposed to be created dynamically.  Talking about the (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5) i dont know the keys for the columns i am only extracting them from the json object that is why i am looping through the Json object ......so working with your idea  can you explain a bit more

Comment: @prashantkumarsingh you will need a cycle to traverse the names of the columns, this is how you get the keys.

Comment: hey, sorry for being unavailable to reply, I looked into your suggestion i can create whole table first but the problem raises when i insert the values because while looping I while get the same problem ... I can use same loop for creating columns can yous suggest me some loop sample which I can implement in the insertion for values ......AND thank you for this much help !!

Comment: @prashantkumarsingh no problem. Please edit your question and add your current attempt, so we can deal with your current situation.